# How to deploy php application on appFog?

Tags: php, deployment, cloud-hosting, appfog

I have install Ruby and gem **af** and I am trying to upload php (not require mysql or other services) application to AppFog.

Directory structure of my application in given in below screenshot.[image: Directory Structure]
In my application file types are :

1. php
2. css
3. images
4. js
5. Jquery

I am applying command from command line and my PWD is **/home/mahesh/test_app**
My application package size is about 2 MB 
I am getting this error
**`Error (JSON 503): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="u...`** 
The thread of command is as below :

```
mahesh@ubuntu:~/test_app$ af push
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: y
Application Name: Image_Editor_test_cld
Detected a Standalone Application, is this correct? [Yn]: n
1: Spring
2: Django
3: Erlang/OTP Rebar
4: Play
5: Rails
6: Lift
7: Grails
8: Sinatra
9: WSGI
10: JavaWeb
11: Rack
12: PHP
13: Node
14: Standalone
Select Application Type: 12
Selected PHP Application
1: AWS US East - Virginia
2: AWS EU West - Ireland
3: AWS Asia SE - Singapore
4: Rackspace AZ 1 - Dallas
5: HP AZ 2 - Las Vegas
Select Infrastructure: 3
Application Deployed URL [Image_Editor_test_cld.ap01.aws.af.cm]:    
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [128M]: 
How many instances? [1]:  
Bind existing services to 'Image_Editor_test_cld'? [yN]: 
Create services to bind to 'Image_Editor_test_cld'? [yN]: 
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: N
Creating Application: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (2M): OK   
Error (JSON 503): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="u...
```

I am making any mistake Is it proper way to upload my application if not then in which way I can upload my application?

I have already upload my simple php application on appFog which contain simple one directory and one .php file. It is working fine.

Comment: You are using GIT for uplaoding?

Comment: Yeah it's for uploading content in PhpFog

Comment: http://docs.phpfog.com/getting-started/git go through documentation....

Comment: Do not use the PHP Fog docs for AppFog. PHP Fog uses git for deploys and AppFog uses the AF command line tool. http://docs.appfog.com/getting-started/af-cli

Comment: I have read that doc.
for deploy from GIT it is necessary to clone repository 
I can't find any URL to clone repository from appFog in console..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `gem update af` to make sure your on the latest version of the `af` tool. There are frequent updates to the `af` tool which fixes issues like this. Then try again.

See if you have the current version:

```
af --version
```

As of writing this, 0.3.18.11 is the current version

Answer (score 0):

I tried logging in again and it worked. Something kicks you out inside of appfog.